# Cannot load native library. Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java

I am having trouble getting Java to see the file 'libvensim.so' that I have in my home directory.

I have tried setting LD_LIBRARY PATH...."echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" returns "./libvensim.so"

When I run the code:

```
java -cp ./vensim.jar:. -Djava.library.path=./libvensim.so Test
```

I get the error "Cannot load native library. Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libvensim in java.library.path".

Test.java is a simple class to test whether I can access the .so:

```
import com.vensim.Vensim;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Vensim vensim = new Vensim("libvensim");

}

}
```

Can anyone see my problem?  Thanks very much.

Comment: LD_LIB.._PATH is a list of folders/directories, NOT libraries. Try: `java -cp ./vensim.jar:. -Djava.library.path=\`pwd\` Test`

Comment: PS: I'm not sure if java.library.path is same as LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So if that doesn't work try `export LD_LIBRARY PATH=\`pwd\`:$LD_LIBRARY PATH; java -cp ./vensim.jar:. Test`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried changing both LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. and -Djava.library.path=. and neither fixed the problem.... I am still seeing "Cannot load native library. Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libvensim.so in java.library.path

Comment: can you run the this and post teh output (want to be sure that it's same shell): `ls -l ./libvensim.so; export LD_LIBRARY PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY PATH; java -cp ./vensim.jar:. Test`

Comment: [dxxxxx@equity4 ~]$ ls -l ./libvensim.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dxxxxx dxxxxx 2084462 Sep  2 17:01 ./libvensim.so
[dxxxxx@equity4 ~]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[dxxxxx@equity4 ~]$ java -cp ./vensim.jar:. Test
Cannot load native library. Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libvensim.so in java.library.path

Comment: Interesting.. How abt permissions? Can you show what's teh real value instead of "dxxxxx dxxxxx"? Also post the code of c'tor: Vensim("libvensim").

Comment: 'dxxxxx' is just concealing my username on the machine.  i don't have the code for the Vensim class, only the vensim.jar file.  thanks for your efforts.

Comment: It'd be hiding the permissions on the file as well. Just because you can see the file via ls -l doesn't mean you can read it as well.
One last thing you can try is to change new `Vensim("libvensim");`
to
`new Vensim("vensim");`
All the best..

Answer (score 1):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should point to the **directory** containing the `.so` files. Try:

```
java -cp ./vensim.jar:. -Djava.library.path=. Test
```

or

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dir
java -cp ./vensim.jar:. Test
```